# problem with finding select element which id attribute Starts With

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

a want that, he found all select elements with id than begins with 'chbTypes' and write something like that

```
$("input[id^='chbTypes']").change(function() { 
//some operations 
});
```

but it's not works.
some idea, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant to use `:input` (which matches `select`, `input`, etc) instead of `input` which only matches `input`.

```
$(":input[id^='chbTypes']");
```

If you want *just* the select elements:

```
$("select[id^='chbTypes']");
```